# Need inputs to optimize Big size Mysql - Innodb Table

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, size, innodb

Number of records in **table_abc: 236,364,206**

**Yearly Records:**

```
Year    Number of records
2009    1
2011    4
2012    8
2013    25
2014    70
2015    175
2016    393
2017    1010
2018    332086
2019    7605438
2020    32268473
2021    73318801
2022    100285147
2023    22554330
```

Index Information

[image: Index Information]

**Problems:**

1. How I can optimize this table on production server.
2. There are unused indexes on this table, which I found from `performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage`, where `count_star = 0`, but I can not directly drop the indexes from production server, as there may be processes which runs monthly or yearly, which may use some of this unused indexes from this table.
3. There is below query, which is using above table and taking approx 7 minutes to execute

```
EXPLAIN SELECT o.*  FROM table_abc o 
WHERE o.cId = '3' AND (o.created <= '2023-04-27 11:45:39' OR o.created IS NULL) AND booking IS NOT NULL AND MOD((o.accId - '19'), 21) = 0 AND o.exported IS NULL
```

Explain OP

[image: Explain OP]

Solutions I am thinking to implement is as follows:

1.

- Need to archive backdated data and need to keep some limited time frame data: As I am new to the application not sure about this.
- Need to create partitions on this table, monthly/yearly

2. What are the prechecks we need to do or we need to take care, to remove the unused indexes from the production server.
   I have prepared the list of unused indexes using performance schema when the DB uptime was 1 day, and after 35 days again I took the list of unused indexes, so like this I covered monthly process, but for yearly one either I need to wait or need to check code to find out which tables are in use for yearly processes. Which is time consuming and again there will be a risk if I miss some processes.
3. I tried to limit the time frame, there is difference in number of rows, but not much difference in execution time.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT o.*  FROM table_abc o 
WHERE o.cId = '3' AND ((**o.created >= '2022-04-27 11:45:39'** AND o.created <= '2023-04-27 11:45:39') OR o.created IS NULL) AND booking IS NOT NULL AND MOD((o.accId - '19'), 21) = 0 AND o.exported IS NULL
```

Explain OP

[image: Explain OP]

Show create table OP:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_abc` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `externalNIId` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `accId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `scheId` int(111) DEFAULT NULL,
  `archiveId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `booking` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `imported` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `accounted` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `payable` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `chargedDepositMonth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `newpayable` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('depo','invo','fee','return_fee','closing','bon','oth','late_int','dunfee_lawyer','liab_depo','liabinvo','liabi_mmma','liab_dunfee','instabonu','addon','emobi','fairness_bonu','cust','msb_bon','commendation_bon','addi_pay','add_fin_pay','derecog_debi','derecog_credi','desir_invo_fee','fle_bonu','fee_in','disconnectfee','reconnectfee','feed_in_remune','ret_deliv_es','cred_one_time_pay','ene_cos_aid_am','depo_sew','depo_wat','invo_sew','invo_wat') NOT NULL,
  `ene` enum('elec','g','wa','sew','he','pre_wat') DEFAULT NULL,
  `groAm` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `setAm` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `tax` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `noti` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wriOffRea` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datevExpo` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstDu` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondDu` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `thirdDu` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `isDe` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isPayblk` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `payBlk` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `exported` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `exportArch` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `moddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL ,
  `extConid` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exteyid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mg_wa` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extalMetParNu` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valAdjAmount` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `txKey` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `txTyp` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bokat` date NOT NULL,
  `isFulset` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isLoc` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `bookingForClient` (`cId`,`booking`),
  KEY `cId` (`cId`),
  KEY `accountId` (`accountId`),
  KEY `scheId` (`scheduleId`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `exported` (`exported`),
  KEY `client_noti` (`cId`,`noti`),
  KEY `accounted` (`accounted`),
  KEY `moddate` (`moddate`),
  KEY `cId_invoid` (`cId`,`invoid`),
  KEY `invoid_idx` (`invoid`),
  KEY `extConid` (`extConid`),
  KEY `exteyid` (`exteyid`),
  KEY `externalNIId` (`externalNIId`),
  KEY `mg_wa` (`mg_wa`),
  KEY `extalMetParNu` (`extalMetParNu`),
  KEY `account_type` (`accountId`,`type`),
  KEY `groAm` (`groAm`),
  KEY `payable` (`payable`),
  KEY `bokat` (`bokat`),
  KEY `account_receivable_idx_accountid_groAm` (`accountId`,`groAm`),
  KEY `account_receivable_idx_cId_created_exported` (`cId`,`created`,`exported`),
  KEY `isFulset` (`isFulset`),
  KEY `account_receivable_idx_invoid_groAm` (`invoid`,`groAm`),
  KEY `boing` (`booking`),
  KEY `book` (`booking`),
  KEY `account_receivables_idx_cId_isFulset_payable` (`cId`,`isFulset`,`payable`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_a_acc` FOREIGN KEY (`accountId`) REFERENCES `acco` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_a_cli` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `clie` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_a_sche` FOREIGN KEY (`sched`) REFERENCES `accr` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=254601015 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**NOTE: I have changed the column names before uploading here.**

Comment: Look into the use of partitions.

Comment: please don't use images; place text directly in your question.   please add the output of `show create table table_abc;`; that is much more helpful than describe or show indexes.

Comment: how many rows have o.Id=3?  do you really have rows with created NULL?  what percentage of rows do just the accountId and booking conditions filter out?

Comment: without more information, I'd guess you want an index on (Id, exported, created) and to move the created is null part to a union'd select (so two union'd selects, one with the created >= and created <=, and the other with created is null, and all the other conditions the same)

Comment: Thanks @ysth for your input, I have added the show create table output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unused indexes" are really used -- OK, leave them in place.

"Optimize" the table -- First, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the more important queries.  With 236M rows, lots of things need to be looked at.

An urgent thing to check on is whether you have any `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` that is likely to overflow 2 (or 4) billion soon.  The `SHOW` will give you a clue.

This query...

```
SELECT  o.*
    FROM  table_abc o
    WHERE  o.Id = '3'
      AND  (o.created <= '2023-04-27 11:45:39'
              OR  o.created IS NULL
           )
      AND  booking IS NOT NULL
      AND  MOD((o.accountId - '19'), 21) = 0
      AND  o.exported IS NULL
```

Notes on that query:

- `OR` is inefficient.  Do you really have some abc's that have never been "created"?
- The `MOD` cuts down on the number of rows delivered, but it does not otherwise speed up the query much.
- If `abc` had `PRIMARY KEY(Id)` then there is only one row.  So I am confused as to why it is slow.  (Again, I need to see the `SHOW`.)
- If `'2023-04-27 11:45:39'` is `NOW()`, imply use `NOW()`.  (No performance improvement, just simplicity.)  Also, is it possible that some rows were created in the future??
- "Using intersect" almost always begs for a composite index:  `INDEX(exported, Id)`
- What version of MySQL?  Newer ones allow *many* index operations to not impact performance.
- Do not rush into `PARTITIONing`.  It is *unlikely* to provide any performance impact.  (I may change my tune after I see the important queries.)

**auto_inc about to overflow**

First, check whether the 236M is the max id currently.  I see from the end of the `CREATE TABLE` shows 254M, so there have been only a few lost values.  This happens with `DELETE`, `INSERT IGNORE`, and many other ways of "burning ids".  The table is  1/16th the way to the max for `INT UNSIGNED` (4 billion).  Your growth rate was tripping every year, but slowed down during Covid.  If it speeds up again, you will hit the max in less than 3 years.  If it levels out, you might last more than 10 years.

The simplest solution is to change id to `BIGINT` in this table *and* in any other table referencing it.  *But* the downtime to do that will be painful -- the `ALTER` will take a long time, regardless of what version of MySQL you are running.

Switching to a different PK is an alternative, but it is more work and not straightforward.  However, you have already identified a candidate:

```
UNIQUE KEY `bookingForClient` (`cId`,`booking`)
```

I hope that neither of those INTs are growing large.

A side effect of changing the PK:  Note that each secondary index has a copy of the PK in its BTree.  You have a huge number (28) of secondary indexes, each of which currently has the 4-byte id tacked on.  That adds up to maybe 40B disk space overhead.  That is, switching `id` to `BIGINT` *or* switching to PK(`cId`,`booking`) will add another 40GB of disk space.

Getting rid of `id` and promoting to `PRIMARY KEY(cId,booking)` would require any other tables that refer to this table to use a different `JOIN..ON` -- this adds coding effort on your part.  There is a bonus -- all indexes *starting with* `cId` (about 5) can be dropped.  Some queries will run faster, some slower.  Probably the overall performance change is for the better.

**Indexes to get rid of**

It is relatively safe to drop `INDEX(a)` when you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.  I see at least 3 cases: `accountId`, `cId`, `invoid`.  The longer index will take over where you need the shorter id.  Ditto for dropping `INDEX(a,b)` when you have `INDEX(a,b,c...)`, though I don't see such a case.

Also, I see one dup index -- `booking`

`INDEX(flag)` is rarely useful.  Here I am assuming `flag` is a column with two (or only a few) distinct values.  Such an index will not be used for any 'common' value, but *may* be useful for a rare (<20%) value.

In contrast, `INDEX(flag, otherCol)` if often useful, regardless of which flag value you are searching for (assuming the `WHERE` clause has *both* columns).

**Vertical split?**

40 columns is somewhat large, but I don't know the app, so I cannot say whether splitting them into two or more tables would be beneficial.  14 Date/Datetime columns seems like a lot, too.

**Datatype Sizes**

Some tables I see have `BIGINT` for all numeric fields; this is a gross waste of most of 8 bytes each.  You have INT, TINYINT, and ENUM.  So, unless some of those INTs (4 bytes) can be shrunk to `MEDIUMINT` or `SMALLINT`, I don't have much to say.  (Note: a one-byte shrinkage equates to 236MB, more if the column is indexed.)

**MySQL 5.7**

Most of the `ALTER TABLE ADD/DROP INDEX` improvements are in your version; I don't see an urgent need to upgrade to 8.0 for that.  However, the upgrade will be time-consuming (not nearly as easy as previous upgrades).

"Index merge intersect" (not 'union') -- as already pointed out, build a composite index, then drop the index containing the *left* column(s) of the new index.

**The 7-minute query**

I see no rational reason why `WHERE o.Id = '3' AND...` did not use the PK for lookup; that should have taken about 1ms, not 420000ms.  `ANALYZE TABLE` is fast and *may* change the statistics such that it will be fast.

Hmmm...  `o.created IS NULL`, yet `created datetime NOT NULL` -- Remove the unnecessary `OR`.

**WHERE PK = constant**

When I see a query that looks up a single row by the PK, I wonder if there was a preceding query that found that `id`.  In general, combining those two queries is possible and will run upwards of twice as fast.

**slowlog**

Analyzing the [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) is a quick way to discover which queries are the "worst".  Fixing the worst would help with performance.  Seeing them would help with question about [*Partitioning.*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Comment: Hello @Rick James, thanks for your time and valuable inputs.
I have added show create table output.
And below are answers  to your questions and few queries:
1.What actions I need to do before Id will overflow. The solution what I understand is increasing the INT size. IF there any other majors to be consider, please let me know.
2.There are 0 records for created IS NULL, we can remove this.
3. Id is not a primary key, I changed the column names while posting, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: 4. INDEX(exported, Id): Do you mean, we need to add composite index on this two columns?
5. Mysql Version : 5.7.12 :(
6. Partitioning: To find important queries related to this table, I need to crawl thorough entire code base, right? or is there any easiest workaround?

Comment: disagree re unused indexes; putting single column indexes on lots of fields like this, that will never actually be a good idea to use individually, does seem to make it do index_merge with disappointing results

Comment: @Rdba - " I changed the column names while posting" -- Please have the query and the CREATE TABLE match.  That way, I can accurately review what INDEX would be best for the query.  And note that removing the NULL check will open extra options for an optimal composite index.  (I answered most of your points.)

Comment: Yes, the null check would need to be removed or the OR implemented by UNION instead

Comment: @ysth - Since it is declared `NOT NULL`, simply remove the `OR`.

Comment: ah, so it is!  that's good

Comment: Hello @Rick James, Thank you so much for your great inputs. I have changed the query as per the column names in show create output. For redundant indexes, we are already started the work to remove those. After removing indexes, should I need to Analyze the table to reconstruct the stats and free up some space?

Comment: Any `ALTER` that changes the indexes will, I think< do the `ANALYZE`.  (It won't hurt do do `ANALYZE` again.)